# Identify the parameter $\alpha$ that forces a row exchange

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

> **Problem.** Consider the system:
>
> $$2x + 6y + z = 1$$ $$3x + \alpha y + z = 6$$ $$0x + 1y - 1z = 3$$
>
> What number $\alpha$ forces a row exchange, and what is the solution
> for that $\alpha$? What $\alpha$ makes the system singular?

---

I'm taking an introductory *linear algebra* course, and I'm stuck on the above problem. The instructor has avoided further clarification.

It isn't clear to me whether there exists a single $\alpha$ that forces a row change (when attempting to solve the system by putting it in RREF form, then performing regression) or, if so, how such a number may be determined.

$\alpha = 6$, for instance, might "force a row change":

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 6 & 1 &|&1\\
3 & 6 & 1 &|&6\\
0&1&-1&|&3
\end{bmatrix} \to \text{subtract (1) from (2)} \to \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 6 & 1 &|&1\\
1 & 0 & 0 &|&5\\
0&1&-1&|&3
\end{bmatrix}$$

...we'd then perhaps want to swap rows (2) and (1). Progressing further, however, it doesn't seem that this system is solvable. Is this "the $\alpha$ that forces a row change"?

Similarly, it isn't clear to me how to identify the $\alpha$ that makes the system singular, outside of simply guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to divide the first equation by $2$; you will get$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y+\frac12z=\frac12\\3x+\alpha y+z=6\\y-z=3.\end{array}\right.$$Then, you add to the second equation by the first one times $-3$:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y+\frac12z=\frac12\\(\alpha-9)y-\frac12z=\frac92\\y-z=3.\end{array}\right.$$And now, if $\alpha=9$, you shall have to exchange the second and the third rows. Otherwise, the natural next step is to divide the second equation by $\alpha-9$. Can you take it form here.